# Babel support for Object.fromEntries

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, babeljs

I am running a React web app inside React Native via [WebView](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/webview/).

The website uses [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) which doesn't appear to be available to the browswer on the device I am using and causes my webapp to crash (with no error) when I try call `Object.fromEntries`.

The device is running Android 8.1.0 so I assume it will be using an older Android browser that doesn't support `Object.fromEntries`.

In my web app babel config I am trying to target Android 8.0 but the app still crashes when `Object.fromEntries` gets called.

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "loose": true,
        "modules": false,
        "shippedProposals": true,
        "targets": {
          "Android": "8.0",
          "browsers": ["last 2 version"]
        }
      }
    ],
    [
      "@babel/preset-react",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": true,
        "pragma": "React.createElement"
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      {
        "loose": true
      }
    ],
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "babel-plugin-macros",
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      {
        "helpers": true,
        "regenerator": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Is there something else I need to include in the babel config or perhaps something that overrides it (i.e. Typescript)?

Comment: _"Is there something else I need to"_ do? Yes. Get rid of Android **8** o.O

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when loading a webpage in an Android 8 Chrome browser. These two changes helped fix it for me:

#### 1. Manually adding polyfills

- https://github.com/es-shims/Object.fromEntries
- https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/main/packages/react-app-polyfill

Add your dependencies

```
yarn add react-app-polyfill
yarn add object.fromentries
```

Then, at the root of your app (`index.js`), add these two imports:

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
import fromEntries from 'object.fromentries';
fromEntries.shim(); // will be a no-op if not needed
```

#### 2. Changing the build target

I'm using `create-react-app` and not directly configuring babel so this may be different for you, but I changed my `browserslist` setting to

```
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all"
```

(This may not be required at all)